# How to share video on facebook wall using android?

Tags: android, facebook

I have tried to share a video on facebook wall using latest facebook SDK doc i.e.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#videos. I have used following code for share video.

```
    ShareVideo video = new ShareVideo.Builder().setLocalUrl(
                    Uri.parse("/sdcard/DCIM/cut.mp4")).build();
            ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                    .setVideo(video).build();               
            shareButton.setShareContent(content);
            shareButton.performClick();
```

but unabe to share video even not show any message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for it, Please use following code instead of hardcoded path(Uri.parse("/sdcard/DCIM/cut.mp4"))).

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dcim = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/cut.mp4");
            Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(dcim);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding setContentUrl("www.example.com") in the code

```
ShareVideo video = new ShareVideo.Builder().setLocalUrl(
                Uri.parse("/sdcard/DCIM/cut.mp4")).build();
ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl("www.example.com") //change with your url
                .setVideo(video).build();
```

Comment: //change with your URL means which one URL, because I tried with my domain name, but it's not working.

Comment: any of the related your content, may be work because i am getting same problem sharePhoto but after adding content uri they work perfect.